# Let $M$ be a boolean matrix. If you replace all the 0's of $M$ with -1's to form matrix $M'$, why is $rank(M) - 1 \leq rank(M') \leq rank(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be a boolean matrix, and let $M'$ be the matrix formed by replacing all the 0's of $M$ with $-1$. If $r = rank(M)$, then why is $r-1 \leq rank(M') \leq r$?

I saw this result in a paper I was reading, and the author wrote that it was obvious. What I know is that if you have two boolean vectors $v, w$ where $v \cdot w = 0$, then $v' = -w'$, where $v'$ and $w'$ replace the 0 entries with -1. This means that 'complementary' boolean vectors will become scalar multiples under this transformation, shrinking the rank by 1. It is also easy to show that you cannot have two pairs of complementary boolean vectors in a linearly independent set.

Given this, I've tried to prove that given a set of linearly dependent $\pm 1$ vectors, show there exists two vectors $v, w$ such that $v = -w$. I haven't been able to prove this either though.

Is this the right approach? Is there some fact about rank that does indeed make this obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "obvious" result is incorrect as stated. In general, we find that
$$
r - 1 \leq \operatorname{rank}(M') \leq r + 1.
$$
To see that this is the case, note that we can write
$$
M' = 2M - J,
$$
where $J$ is the matrix with the same shape as $M$ whose entries are all $1$. Notably, $J$ is a rank-$1$ matrix. As such, applying the general inequality $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$ leads to
$$
\operatorname{rank}(2M - J) \leq \operatorname{rank}(2M) + \operatorname{rank}(-J) = r + 1\\
\operatorname{rank}(2M) \leq \operatorname{rank}(2M - J) + \operatorname{rank}(J) \implies \operatorname{rank}(2M - J) \geq r-1.
$$
As examples where equality is attained for each bound, consider
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} \implies M' = \pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}, \quad \operatorname{rank}(M') = \operatorname{rank}(M) - 1\\
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \implies 
M' = \pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&-1}, \quad \operatorname{rank}(M') = \operatorname{rank}(M) + 1.
$$

Comment: The incorrect bound was my bad, the paper stated that the rank changed by at most 1, and I just assumed it would not increase. This is really nice; I tried using the additive inequality, but never noticed that $M' = 2M - J$.

Comment: Does it hold true that the rank decreases if and only if there are two columns of $M$ which are complements? As well, does the rank increase if and only if there is an all $0$ column of $M$?

Comment: @StefanG. To the first, the answer is no. For instance,
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1}
$$

Comment: @StefanG. For the second, I suspect that the answer is also know but I can't think of a nice way to construct a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: That matrix has complementary rows though. So I guess, what if no complementary columns or rows?

Comment: @StefanG. Take
$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The matrix is invertible (with determinant $-2$) but $M'$ is not.

Comment: @StefanG. For the second question, 
$$
M = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]
$$
I have confirmed that there are no examples of size $2$ or $3$.

Answer (score 0):

For the left side, I notice that $M'=2M-\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^nE_{ij}$, where $E_{ij}$ denotes elementary matrixs with the (i,j) entry "1".

And there is a fact that $r(A-B)\leqslant|r(A)-r(B)|$, Since the rank of $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^nE_{ij}$ is $1$, so we complete the left and even get $r(M')\leqslant r(M)+1$.